# Stripe API - Filtering Dispute Requests

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm in the process of requesting all disputes from the [Python Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/object). My current code to retrieve all disputes is below.

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "12345"

disputes = stripe.Dispute.list(limit=100)
```

However, I only want to request disputes containing the `status` of `needs_response`. Is there a specific way to request these disputes in the Stripe API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here is to do the filtering locally after retrieving the complete list of `disputes` from the API. Using [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=python), this can be as simple as:

```
disputes = stripe.Dispute.list(limit=3)

for dispute in disputes.auto_paging_iter():
    if (dispute.status == 'needs_response'):
        # Do something with the dispute
```

As an generalization, if it's not in the [arguments list for that resource](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/list) then you'll want to just do any further filtering locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = get_stripe()
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import delorean
dt = datetime.utcnow()
lte = delorean.Delorean(dt, timezone="UTC").epoch
a =  datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-2)
gte = delorean.Delorean(a, timezone="UTC").epoch
chuck = stripe.Dispute.list(created={'gte':int(gte),'lte':int(lte)})
print "NUMBER OF DISPUTES:", len(chuck)

ch_lst = []
id_lst = []
name_lst = []
am_lst = []
f_lst = []


for d in chuck.auto_paging_iter():
    for d in chuck.auto_paging_iter():
        if (d['status'] == 'needs_response' or d['status'] == 'warning_needs_response'):
        c = stripe.Charge.retrieve(str(d['charge']))
        ch_lst.append(str(d['charge']))
        id_lst.append(str(d['id']))
        am_lst.append(str(c['amount']))
        name_lst.append(str(c['source']['name']))
        f_lst.append(str(c['source']['fingerprint']))
```

Comment: So with this code, you will get all Disputes from the current day to the last 2 days ( you can adjust the days on Line 7). Then the code auto page true the list only looking for Disputes where the status equals to needs_response or warning_needs_response.

If its status equals to needs_response or warning_needs_response, the code goes to the charge and append the charge amount, name and fingerprint. The code also append the dispute id

Comment: Better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54819003/edit) you answer to add those inside it :)